# C# Datagridview sort numeric string which are divided by slash

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

is there a way to sort a numeric string, that looks like this :

[image]

so that it will be as follows :

```
50/51
44/148
42/51
6/12
6/12
5/8
5/13
5/13
5/12
4/4
4/26
```

(Sorted by the number before `/` )

Right now it is being sorted by the very first number.

I dont have any `DataSource` , i add the columns with `Columns.Add`.
Or maybe there is a way to convert it in to an `int`?.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: You were not clear on the sort criterion.  What is Size?

Comment: @Roma I'm very sorry i have edited the question !!

Comment: what do you mean by manually? harcoded or else?

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 , i mean . That i the columns by using `Column.Add`

Comment: Roma answer will work @Bongskie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse part of string to `int` and sort using `OrderByDescending()`:

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderByDescending(i => Convert.Int32(i.Split('/')[0])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to accomplish your task:

1. You will need to implement your own sort function by implementing the IComparer interface.

   Your comparer should extract the number before the slash / using the string functions indexOf, SubString or a real expression.

   MSDN gives a nice example here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. You could do the same operation described above to extract the number and the run a Linq query.  If your column results are loaded into a list you can do this:

   `myList = customerList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Code)).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

There are few "easier" options. One is to pad space to the values when or after they are added:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var cell = dataGridView1[0, i];
    var strValue = cell.Value?.ToString();
    cell.Value = strValue?.PadLeft(strValue.Length + strValue.IndexOf("/"));
}
```

or, if the second number should be sorted by numerically too, pad non-printable characters to their left:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var cell = dataGridView1[0, i];
    if (cell.Value != null)
        cell.Value = string.Join("/", cell.Value.ToString().Split('.').Select(s => s.PadLeft(5, '\t')));
}

dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

---

Another option can be to convert the values to numbers (`50.51`) and change the decimal separator:

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci;
```